# Upper and right border disappear from Matlab R2014a figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to create figures for my analyses and for some reason the top and right border of my figure disappears:

[image]

This problem doesn't happen always so it's a bit mystery for me. I also noticed earlier that for older version of Matlab this also doesn't happen. Any idea what might be causing this? I'm using very basic commands in Matlab R2014a such as `plot, xlim, grid on`. Is there a way to manually set the border?

Thank you

P.S.

here is a part of my code where I do the plotting:

```
    figure(1)
    hold on
    m = mean(datamatrix,2);
    s = std(datamatrix, 0, 2);
    handles1 = [handles1, plot(40:20:400, m, 'color', colors(k,:), 'LineWidth', 2)];
    plot(40:20:400, m-s, '--', 'color', colors(k,:), 'LineWidth', 2)
    plot(40:20:400, m+s, '--', 'color', colors(k,:), 'LineWidth', 2)
```

P.S.

here is a MWE where I get this problem in Matlab R2014a:

```
figure(1)
hold on
n = 5
colors = rand(n,3);
for i = 1:n
    datamatrix = ones(10,1) + rand(10,1);
    plot(1:10, datamatrix, 'LineWidth', 2, 'color', colors(i,:))
end
```

If I run this code this is what I get (by setting n=5):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may control the outer box with

```
box on
```

or

```
box off
```

Comment: Thank you that did it! =) The `box on` solved the problem